# How to find specific column in SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server

Is there any way or tool in SQL Server 2016 to find a column in the entire database based on the name?

Example: find `ProductNumber` and it shows you all the table(s) that have it

Comment: `select * from information_schema.columns where column_name = 'ProductNumber'`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can query the database's `information_schema.columns` table which holds the schema structure of all columns defined in your database.

Using this query:

```
select * from information_schema.columns where column_name = 'ProductNumber'
```

The result would give you the columns:

`TABLE_NAME`, `TABLE_CATALOG`, `DATA_TYPE` and more properties for this database column.

Comment: Being pedantic `information_schema.columns` is a view rather than a table per se. Admittedly it doesn't really matter in a query but it might help others find it in SSMS to know they need to look in `Views` rather than `Tables`.

Comment: @Caltor Sometimes comments like these make the day.. `information_schema..` is a `view` was a good thing!

Answer (score 4):

Several options are available to you:

```
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE column_name = 'YourColumnName';

-- OR

SELECT col.name, tab.name
FROM sys.columns col
INNER JOIN sys.tables tab
  ON tab.object_id = col.object_id
WHERE col.name = 'YourColumnName';
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Query as below:

```
select * 
from information_schema.columns 
where column_name = 'ProductNumber'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to find database objects (e.g. tables, columns, triggers) by name - have a look at the **FREE** Red-Gate tool called [SQL Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/) which does this - it searches your entire database for any kind of string(s).

[image]

[image]

It's a great must-have tool for any DBA or database developer - did I already mention it's absolutely **FREE** to use for any kind of use??

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
so.name "table name", 
sc.name "column name"
FROM sysobjects so
INNER JOIN syscolumns sc
ON so.id = sc.id
WHERE --so.type='U'
```

--and

```
sc.name like '%ProductN%'
order by so.name asc
```